# Why is sunspot returning all results when I provide a particular param?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sunspot, sunspot-rails

I am following: [Railscasts 278](http://railscasts.com/episodes/278-search-with-sunspot?view=asciicast) and have the following:

```
 def search 
    if params[:search] == ''
      @search_results = []
    else
      @search = Challenge.search do
        fulltext params[:search]
      end
      @search_results = @search.result
    end
  end
```

**Model**

```
 searchable do 
    text :title, :location, :boost => 5
    text :location
    time :created_at
    string :most_participated
  end

  def most_participated
    Participation.group('challenge_id').order('COUNT(challenge_id) DESC')
  end
```

My issue is when I search for something particular I returned all records. My logs are provided here:

> Started GET "/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=Test" for 127.0.0.1 at
>   2015-05-14 21:39:15 +0100 Processing by ChallengesController#search as
>   HTML   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "search"=>"Test"}   User Load (0.4ms)
>   SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users`  WHERE `users`.`id` = 2  ORDER BY
>   `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1   Challenge Load (0.6ms)  SELECT
>   `challenges`.* FROM `challenges`   Rendered challenges/search.html.erb
>   within layouts/application (10.6ms)

**Update**

Anyone who does get stuck with this. DO not do `ClassName.search` for some unknown reason it doesn't work. So I did `Sunspot.search(User) do` ... The railscast is outdated